# How to identify relevant columns in very wide tables using AI and Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-modeling

I have a complex data model consisting of around hundred tables containing business data. Some tables are very wide, up to four hundred columns. Columns can have various data types - integers, decimals, text, dates etc. I'm looking for a way to identify relevant / important information stored in these tables.

I fully understand that business knowledge is essential to correctly process a data model. What I'm looking for are some strategies to pre-process tables and identify columns that should be taken to later stage where analysts will actually look into it. For example, I could use data profiling and statistics to find and exclude columns that don't have any data at all. Or maybe all records have the same value. This way I could potentially eliminate 30% of fields. However, I'm interested in exploring how AI and Machine Learning techniques could be used to identify important columns, hoping I could identify around 80% of relevant data. I'm aware, that relevant information will depend on the questions I want to ask. But even then, I hope I could narrow the columns to simplify the manual assesment taking place in the next stage.

**Could anyone provide some guidance on how to use AI and Machine Learning to identify relevant columns in such wide tables?** What strategies and techniques can be used to pre-process tables and identify columns that should be taken to the next stage?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

F.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach I've seen to evaluate the analytical utility of columns is the correlation method. This would tell you if there is a relationship (positive or negative) among specific column pairs. In my experience you'll be able to more easily build analysis outputs when columns are correlated - although, these analyses may not always be the most accurate.

However, before you even do that, like you indicate, you would probably need to narrow down your list of columns using much simpler methods. For example, you could surely eliminate a whole bunch of columns based on datatype and basic count statistics.

Less common analytic data types (ids, blobs, binary, etc) can probably be excluded first, followed by running simple `COUNT(Distinct(ColName))`, and `Count(*) where ColName is null` . This will help to eliminating UniqueIDs, Keys, and other similar data types. If all the rows are distinct, this would not be a good field for analysis. Same process for NULLs, if the percentage of nulls is greater than some threshold then you can eliminate those columns as well.

In order to automate it depending on your database, you could create a fairly simple stored procedure or function that loops through all the tables and columns and does a data type, count_distinct and a null percentage analysis on each field.

Once you've narrowed down list of columns, you can consider a [.corr() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-corr/) to run the analysis against all the remaining columns in something like a Python script.
If you wanted to keep everything in the database, Postgres also supports a `corr()` [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html), but you'll only be able to run this on 2 columns at a time, like this:

> `SELECT corr(column1,column2) FROM table;`

so you'll need to build a procedure that evaluates multiple columns at once.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about this tech challenges for some time. In general it’s AI solvable problem since there are easy features to extract such as unique values, clustering, distribution, etc.

And we want to bake this ability in https://columns.ai, obviously we haven’t gotten there yet, the first step we have done though is to collect all columns stats upon a data connection, identify columns that have similar range of unique values and generate a bunch of query templates for users to explore its dataset.

If interested, please take a look, as we keep advancing this part, it will become closer to an AI model to find relevant columns. Cheers!